# foreach does not fill array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, directory-structure

I am trying to scan a folderstructure recursively and fill an array with paths to every found file. 
However `print_r($fileArray)` gives me an empty array as output? Like this: `Array ( )`

Where is the mistake?

```
function getFilePaths($path){
    $structureArray = [];
    $fileArray = [];

    foreach(new DirectoryIterator($path) as $item){

        if($item->isDir()){
            if(!$item->isDot()) { 
                $structureArray[$item->getFilename()] = getFilePaths($item->getPathname());
            }
            continue;
        }

        $fileArray[] = '"'. $item->getPathname() .'"';
    } 

    return $fileArray;
}
```

**Update**

output of var_dump( $item ); inside your foreach:

```
object(DirectoryIterator)#9 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(68) "music\sorted\3 Doors Down\Seventeen Days\01 Right Where I Belong.mp3" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(27) "01 Right Where I Belong.mp3" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#9 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(59) "music\sorted\3 Doors Down\Seventeen Days\02 It's Not Me.mp3" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(18) "02 It's Not Me.mp3" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#9 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(58) "music\sorted\3 Doors Down\Seventeen Days\AlbumArtSmall.jpg" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(17) "AlbumArtSmall.jpg" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#9 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(51) "music\sorted\3 Doors Down\Seventeen Days\Folder.jpg" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(10) "Folder.jpg" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#9 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(59) "music\sorted\3 Doors Down\The Better Life\01 Kryptonite.mp3" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(17) "01 Kryptonite.mp3" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#9 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(54) "music\sorted\3 Doors Down\The Better Life\02 Loser.mp3" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(12) "02 Loser.mp3" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#9 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(59) "music\sorted\3 Doors Down\The Better Life\AlbumArtSmall.jpg" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(17) "AlbumArtSmall.jpg" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#9 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(52) "music\sorted\3 Doors Down\The Better Life\Folder.jpg" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(10) "Folder.jpg" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#5 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(55) "music\unsorted\01 Club Rocker (Mike Candys Radio Ed.mp3" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(40) "01 Club Rocker (Mike Candys Radio Ed.mp3" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#7 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(69) "music\unsorted\tagged\257ers - Bis dahin bin ich tot ft. Favorite.mp3" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(47) "257ers - Bis dahin bin ich tot ft. Favorite.mp3" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" } object(DirectoryIterator)#7 (4) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(62) "music\unsorted\tagged\257ers - Seite an Seite ft. Favorite.mp3" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(40) "257ers - Seite an Seite ft. Favorite.mp3" ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=> bool(false) ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Do some debugging within your foreach.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump( $item );` inside your `foreach`?

Comment: `$fileArray` will be empty if you always hit the `continue` statement. As @Jessica points out , a bit of debugging would be helpful. Also, what is the point of `$structureArray` if you neither use it nor return it to the caller ?

Comment: Updated the Question. `$structureArray` is truly not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this code to generate list of php files in a directory, and remove the extension ".php" from each file name

without the use of DirectoryIterator

```
function getFiles($directory){
        $files = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('.','..','.htaccess'));
        foreach($files as $f){
            if(strstr($f, ".php"))
                $fileArray[] = str_replace(".php","",$f);
            else {
                $fileArray[$f] = getFiles($directory."/".$f);
            }
        }
        return $fileArray;
    }
```

P.S. all file names will be in a single array, even files in subdirectories

Comment: this does what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you tried this already but `glob($file_path."*");` should return all files in a given folder.  It is built into php and considerably shorter.